# I am trying to find a way though which i can create diffrent variations for products in sql and diffrent price for every schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hello folks I am creating an ecommerce marketplace using postgresql and sequelizeORM and nodejs for backend ,so i am stuck that would be the best way ? that i could add different variations for single product an different prices for it for example like - Anime tshirt colors like red, blue, yellow and different designs so every time different variation their is a different price for it so can someone would help me with scheme for it i would be very thankful the person for helping me since i have been stuck on this from weeks

I searched on google and other platform but couldn't find something similar would be very helpful if someone helps

Comment: Seems like this question is more related to DB structure rather than to Sequelize. As for a structure it all depends on how you see and what you want to store in products, their variations and prices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need two tables: Products and Variations. Products table contains only the common information each. The Variations contains the details of the variants. This separation is the process of *normalization*; which you should probably research and become familiar with as it is central to the design of a database (RDBMS). The following shows a very basic design: ( see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WIW9-qXr))

```
create table products ( prod_id     integer  generated always as identity
                                             primary key
                      , name        text     not null
                      , description text
                      ); 

create table variations( var_id    integer  generated always as identity
                                            primary key
                       , prod_id   integer  references products(prod_id)
                       , size      text
                       , color     text
                       , cost      numeric (6,2)
                       );
```

With this you can build the appropriate queries.

Comment: oh thanks @belayer for helping me i would jusr go and try creating it